# Untagged question still appear in search results of the removed tag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37745138) had a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, and therefore appeared in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python.

I edited the question and removed the `python` tag, but this question still appears with the rest of the `python` tagged question.

Comment: By the time you posted this, tag engine has caught up with your tag change.